# Incompatible library version: libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 9.0.0

Tags: c, opencv, caffe

Im trying to run the runtest of caffe to complete the instalattion, but I get the following message:

**dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 9.0.0
make: *** **[runtest] Trace/BPT trap: 5****

I'm using OSX el capitan and following the instructions of Caffe home page. caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html. Open CV was installed following the same instructions of caffe installation.
Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of: caffe, opencv, OS (yeah we can guess it is a Mac from the error but which Mac OSX)?  What commands did you use?  What documentation are you following?

Comment: I'm using OSX el capitan and followings the instruction of Caffe home page. http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html. Open CV was installed following the same instructions of caffe installation.